# Как реализовать метод отправки фото телеграм ботом на java?

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Имеется телеграмм бот с возможностью ответа на текстовые сообщения, хочется реализовать функцию, которая по ключевому слову будет выдавать картинку из папки на компьютере или облачном хранилище, хотелось бы узнать, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите документацию на сайте телеграм. Там должен быть необходимый вам метод. Возможно вам очень поможет данный сайт:[surgebook]

https://www.surgebook.com/open/book/pishem-telegram-bota-na-java/sozdanie-bota